# How do I generate a custom menu/sub-menu system using wp_get_nav_menu_items in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, submenu

I have an html structure that requires customization of the `wp_nav_menu` code.

This is the html I need to generate:

```
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/?p=123" class="title">Title</a>
        <a href="http://example.com/?p=123" class="desc">Description</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="item">
                <a href="http://example.com/?p=123" class="title">Title</a>
                <a href="http://example.com/?p=123" class="desc">Description</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/?p=123" class="title">Title</a>
        <a href="http://example.com/?p=123" class="desc">Description</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am currently using `wp_get_nav_menu_items` to get all the items from my menu as an array.

Right now I am able to generate the above html **without the sub-menus** using the following code:

```
<?php

$menu_name = 'main-nav';
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations()
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
$menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

foreach ( $menuitems as $item ):

    $id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
    $page = get_page( $id );
    $link = get_page_link( $id ); ?>

    <li class="item">
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title">
            <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
        </a>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="desc">
            <?php echo $page->post_excerpt; ?>
        </a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would have generated the menu using the `wp_nav_menu` function but I still need the description shown using `$page->post_excerpt`.

I've found that there is a property for each item called `$item->menu_item_parent` which gives the ID of the parent menu item.

How would I generate the sub-menu in my `foreach` loop?
Or is there a really simple way using `wp_nav_menu` which Google forgot to mention?

Comment: you may wish to post this on the WordPress Stack Exchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dnagirl I think this is more of a programming question. I'm not sure how many people would actually be able to answer this on wp stackexchange.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For anyone who tackles something similar here's my solution:

### Quick code example on a gist

[Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/4345363) on a github gist for anyone who wants to get in on the copy paste action.

### TL;DR

TL;DR Loop over list, drill down if there's a sub menu, close if we reach the end of the sub menu and menu.

### Complete Code explanation

Firstly get the menu items as a flat array:

```
<?php
$menu_name = 'main_nav';
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
$menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
?>
```

Then iterate over the array of the menu items:

```
<nav>
<ul class="main-nav">
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $submenu = false;

    foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
        // set up title and url
        $title = $item->title;
        $link = $item->url;

        // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
        if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):

        // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
        $parent_id = $item->ID;
    ?>
```

Write the first parent item `<li>`:

```
    <li class="item">
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title">
            <?php echo $title; ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Check that this items' parent id matches the stored parent id:

```
        <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>
```

Start sub-menu `<ul>` and set `$submenu` flag to true for later referance:

```
            <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Write the sub-menu item:

```
                <li class="item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                </li>
```

If the next item does not have the same parent id and we have a sub-menu declared then close the sub-menu `<ul>`

```
            <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
            </ul>
            <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Again, if the next item in the array does not have the same parent id close the `<li>`

```
    <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
    </li>                           
    <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

<?php $count++; endforeach; ?>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: There's a missing semi-colon in the first section of code. Also, it's really difficult to copy and paste your solution. I'd have preferred a single block of code with in-code comments. Thanks for your answer, though. +1 from me

Comment: @matt Thanks for the comment, I added a gist and added the missing semicolon.

Comment: I think the closing tags for the first two lines, <nav> and <ul>, are also missing?

Comment: @matt They were in the markup but were hidden. I updated the gist as well. Cheers!

Comment: Add `(array)` in `foreach( (array) $menuitems as $item )`.

Comment: @hitautodestruct, I just updated your answer. Without `(array)` it would return error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Comment: @Binyamin Could it be related to the php version?

Comment: The Problem with this solution is that it can only display level 1 sub items. If you have sub items which have sub items it does not work properly anymore.

Comment: thanx alot ... its really helped

Answer (score 12):

Your best bet is to make your own Walker class to tailor the output to your needs. Something like this:

```
class Excerpt_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';

        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

        /*GET THE EXCERPT*/
        $q = new WP_Query(array('post__in'=>$item->object_id));
        if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
            $item_output .= '<span class="menu-excerpt">'.get_the_excerpt().'</span>';
        endwhile;endif;
        /*****************/

        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array('walker' => new Excerpt_Walker()));
?>
```

Everything before and after the GET THE EXCERPT marker in my example was a direct copy of the start_el function in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php. My example uses WP_Query to determine if the post/page has an excerpt, and places the excerpt in between span tags after the link title.

An idea would be to make the span tags appear only upon hover, which can be done using CSS.

More information on Walkers here:

[WP Nav Menu Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

[Using The Walker Class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039)

[Another Decent Example Using the Walker Class](http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/)

Comment: I took a look at walkers and they are far too complex for my meager needs. I ended up with a simpler solution.

Comment: Glad it all worked out for you. Still, keep Walkers in the back of your mind, as they've helped me in a pinch with some pretty..... interesting client requests.

Comment: It doesn't respect the parent structure, you can see it here: http://i.imgur.com/jIOXu4e.png

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales That doesn't show me anything. Are you using menus? Did you you define your menu in the dashboard? Are you calling the appropriate menu in your template? Are you sure your menu isn't falling back to `wp_page_menu`? If you did everything correctly, then this *will* respect the parent structure, as this is almost an exact replica of the original Walker class Wordpress uses internally.

Answer (score 0):

```
      //Just set your variable and apply.. for sub menu
     <ul>
     <?php

     $activeclass = '';
    $activeclass1='';
     $count=0;
    $submenu = FALSE;
    foreach ( $primaryNav as $navItem ) {
            $activeclass = '';  
         if($navItem->object_id == $getid){
            $activeclass = 'class="live-act"';
         }
         if (!$navItem->menu_item_parent ){
            $parent_id = $navItem->ID;
        echo '<li><a href="'.$navItem->url.'" '.$activeclass.'   title="'.$navItem->title.'">'.$navItem->title.'</a>';
         }
         ?>
        <?php if ( $parent_id == $navItem->menu_item_parent ) { ?>
      <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
        <ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
             <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $navItem->url; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $navItem->title; ?></a>
            </li>
       <?php if ( $primaryNav[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ){ ?>
        </ul>
        <?php $submenu = false; 
       }
        ?>
        <?php }
         if ( $primaryNav[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ){ ?>
        </li>                            
            <?php $submenu = false; } ?>

        <?php $count++;   ?>


        <?php } ?>
         </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Code explanation.....**

First Create two below two functions in functions.php file

```
 function get_menu_id( $location ){
                //get all the location....
                $locations =get_nav_menu_locations();
    
                //get object id by location.....
                $menu_id = $locations[$location];
                
                return !empty($menu_id) ? $menu_id : '';
            }


            function get_child_menu_items($menu_array , $parent_id){
                $child_menu = [];
                if(!empty($menu_array) && is_array($menu_array)){
                    foreach($menu_array as $menu){
                        if( intval($menu->menu_item_parent) === $parent_id){
                            array_push($child_menu , $menu);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return $child_menu;
            }
```

then

```
$menu_name = 'menu_name';
                $location = get_nav_menu_locations();
                $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($location[$menu_name]);
                $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id);
                $header_menu_id = get_menu_id('primary-menu');
                
                $header_menus = wp_get_nav_menu_items($header_menu_id);
```

now this is my html and php code....

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">


                    <?php
                        if(!empty($header_menus)  && is_array($header_menus)){
                            ?>
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <?php
                                    foreach($header_menus as $menu_item){
                                        if(!$menu_item->menu_item_parent){ //checking the item are parent?
                                            $child_menu_items = get_child_menu_items($header_menus, $menu_item->ID);
                                            $has_children = !empty($child_menu_items) && is_array($child_menu_items);

                                            if(! $has_children){
                                                ?>
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo esc_url($menu_item -> url); ?>"> <?php echo esc_html($menu_item->title); ?></a> 
                                                </li>
                                                <?php
                                            }else{
                                                ?>
                                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="<?php echo esc_url($menu_item -> url); ?>" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                <?php echo esc_html($menu_item->title); ?>
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                                    <?php
                                                        foreach($child_menu_items as $child){
                                                            ?>
                                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo esc_url($child->url); ?>" > <?php echo esc_html($child->title); ?></a> 
                                                            <?php
                                                        }
                                                    ?>        
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleae try this. It works for me.

```
<?php
        $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations();
        $menuID = $menuLocations['primary'];
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($menuLocations['primary']);
        $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id, array('order' => 'DESC'));
        $ParentArray = array();
        $count = 0;
        $submenu = false;

    foreach ($menuitems as $menu_item) {
        $link = $menu_item->url;
        $title = $menu_item->title;
        if ($menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0   ) {
            $parent_id = $menu_item->ID;
            echo  '<li class="main-li dropmenu"><a href="' .$menu_item->url . '">'.$menu_item->title .'</a>';
        }
        if ($parent_id == $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) {
            if (!$submenu ) {
                $submenu = true;
                echo '<ul class="level1">';
            }
             echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a></li>';
            if ($menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ) {
                echo '</ul>';
                $submenu = false;
            }
        }
        if ($menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ) {
            echo '</li>';
            $submenu = false;
        }
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your theme uses `has_nav_menu('<menu-name>')` in the `header` or `footer.php`(for example), you can go to  `Appearance > Menus` and select which **menu** or **sub-menu** to configure.