# How do I add HTML to a Wordpress menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

Say I have MyAccount and MyStats in navigation and I want to wrap a  tag around the 'My' text. How would I do this in Wordpress?

e.g **My**House, **My**Street.

Comment: Are you using any javascript/jQuery ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you just want to make the word "My" bold? Take a look at this screen shot, you should be able to post it right into the Nav menu, depending on exactly what you want to add:

[image]

Comment: This would have been ideal. I used a more complicated solution below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **jQuery** you could do something like this in order to wrap the first two letters of each menu item with a `<span>` element.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<span>'+$(this).text().substring(0,2)+'</span>'+$(this).text().substring(2));
});
```

You may need to change the selector, or be more specific in order that you don't effect all the `li`'s on your site.

Here is a working fiddle - [http://jsfiddle.net/dM5sb/](http://jsfiddle.net/dM5sb/1/)

For a **PHP** solution if you are currently using `wp_nav_menu()` you might want to switch over to `get_pages()` and do something like this.

```
<ul>

<?php

$args = array(
'sort_order' => 'ASC',
'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
'hierarchical' => 1,
'child_of' => 0,
'parent' => -1,
'offset' => 0,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
); 

$pages = get_pages($args); 

foreach($pages as $page) {

    $title = $page->post_title;
    $my = substr($title, 0, 2);
    $the_rest = substr($title, 2);

?>

<li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><span><?php echo $my ?></span><?php echo $the_rest?></a></li>

<?php } ?>

</ul>
```

This is untested, but you can read more about the wordpress `get_pages()` function here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: I thought of this but I would rather use PHP.

Comment: I have just added an option for using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this by editing your head.php/header.php file most likely. To do this you will need to do one of two things. Either FTP into your server and navigate to

```
sitefolder/wp-content/themes/themefolder/header.php
```

and find either nav or menu. Alternatively in the back end of wordpress, go to

```
appearance->editor
```

find the file here and make the necessary changes.

With this method you will need to hardcode the menu item in. Therefore any changes to page name etc will not be represented. But this is the easiest method to do this.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should have said. I am not expecting to get this to work using the GUI. I expect I will have to edit my template some more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom navigation names you could simply make a custom menu:

[image: Getting there]

[image: Modifying it]

[image: Selecting it]

Answer (score 0):

**This link helped me alot to get what I wanted:**
[How do I generate a custom menu/sub-menu system using wp_get_nav_menu_items in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935423/how-do-i-generate-a-custom-menu-sub-menu-system-using-wp-get-nav-menu-items-in-w)

I would put my code in here if getting the code to validate was such a problem.

**Thanks for your answers**