# Add a <div> after <li> in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I use this script to show the wordpress menu

```
<?php  
   $argsM = array(
      'theme_location'  => 'menu-principal',
      'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="sf-menu nav navbar-nav %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
   );
   wp_nav_menu( $argsM );
?>
```

And it gives me a regular menu as

```
ul
  li - home
  li - shop
  li - contact us
ul
```

I try to find a way where I can put a div after each li for something similar to this

```
ul
  li - home
   div
  li - shop
   div
  li - contact us
   div
ul
```

I want to go this way if it's possible and not with a jQuery solution .append() or something else like that.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935423/how-do-i-generate-a-custom-menu-sub-menu-system-using-wp-get-nav-menu-items-in-w

Comment: By "after" you actually mean "in", yes? (Because "after" would not be valid HTML to begin with, div can not be a child of ul.)